# session[:user_id] returns false WHY? RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sessionid

I'm debugging my parks_controller.rb create method because I want to create the park for current user but the current_user method returns nil.

here is the create method:

```
def create
@park = current_user.parks.new(park_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @park.save
    format.html { redirect_to @park, notice: 'Park was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @park }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @park.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

here is the current_user method:

```
def current_user
if session[:user_id]
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  puts "There was no problem"
else
  puts "There was a problem"
end
end
```

It prints out "There was a problem." Here is the user_sessions_controller.rb:

```
def create
user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  flash[:success] = I18n.t("thanks_log_in")
  redirect_to parks_path
else
  flash[:error] = I18n.t("login_problem")
  render action: 'new'
end
end
```

All of my tests are passing except when I try to save the park to the current user, the tests for POST create in parks_controller_spec.rb start to fail and Im done. What am I doing wrong? Where should I look? I already spent at least 10 hours on this and I'm desperate. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Break the problem step-by-step. Do "puts" in various places to print session[:user_id] in create method to check what value it returns or check whether it actually passes the authentication..

Comment: Well, I did as you suggested and I got stuck again. I sense the solution is seconds away but I'm a newbie so please forgive me. So, now I fixed the session[:user_id] and it authenticates correctly. I know this because I run current_user: `code` def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
      puts @current_user.parks.count
    end
  end `code` and it returns 0. So the current_user is not nil and the class parks is defined. But when it returns to parks' create class current_user is Nil again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did it show `thanks_log_in`?

Comment: well, now im confused more than ever. the spec for user_sessions_controller run smoothly but when I run the application, and try to login it always renders the form again. OMG, this is nuts. spent the whole day trying to fix this :-(

Comment: I think your previous session is active still. Your app sessions will not be cleared unless you have logout functionality. Try clear your active sessions in browser by pressing "Ctrl+Shift+Del" button in your browser and enable "Active Session" checkbox and Clear it!!. Try running your application again now.. Also, make sure the class of the current_user method is the parent class of park class. If current_user is nil in park controller, it means it is not inherited in park class.